# How do I find the id of the minimum value of an array in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, position

I have a random value in my *ComboBox.Text* and I need to find the nearest value in all my *ComboBox.Items* and finally set this value in the *ComboBox.Text*

My code is already finding the closest value but I don't know what is the id of this number to associate it to my *ComboBox.Items*:

```
Function FindItemcbxWR()
        Dim i, x(3) As Integer
        For i = 0 To 3
            x(i) = Math.Abs(CInt(Me.cbxWR.Text) - CInt(Me.cbxWR.Items(i)))
        Next
        x.Min() 'I already know
        Return 'I don't know how to proceed to get my id of my x.Min() to return
End Function
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim closeValueID As Integer
        closeValueID = FindItemcbxWR()
        Me.cbxWR.Text = Me.cbxWR.Items(closeValueID)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to return the index of the closest value from the ComboBox, you need to keet track of which value is currently the closest as you loop through all the ComboBox items.

```
Function FindItemcbxWR() As Integer
    Dim ind As Integer, diff As Integer = Integer.MaxValue 
    For i As Integer = 0 To cbxWR.Items.Count - 1
        Dim diffTest As Integer = Math.Abs(CInt(cbxWR.Text) - CInt(cbxWR.Items(i)))
        If diffTest < diff Then
            ind = i 
            diff = diffTest 
        End If
    Next
    Return ind
End Function
```

Comment: But is there no way to do this directly? I mean order the id of this number? By the way, thank you

Comment: @EricHideki If you mean is there a way to do this in a single statement, I can't think of one (and if there is one, it would probably be complex and hard to read).